# Multiple ranges in Query for elasticsearch

Tags: php, elasticsearch

I would like make query like `where price > 555 and price < 5555 and quantity > 33`

I have query like:

```
$query = array(
            'query' => queryFilters($filters),
            'sort' => array($sortOrder[0] => $sortOrder[1], 'updated_at' => 'desc'),
            'from' => ($page - 1) * $pageSize,
            'size' => $pageSize,
        );
```

Now, lets assume my filters is like:

```
filter[price_from]=555&filter[price_to]=5555&filter[quantity_from]=33
```

What should be result of `queryFilters($filters)` to make it work?
I tried filtered query from [this doc](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/combining-filters.html) but result was like or (used `array of ranges: 0=>range[...], 1=>range[...], 2=>range[...])` but result was like or query. Any suggestions?
I will have `query=>constant_score=>filter=>exists=>field[items]` and [missing](same structure) in result of `queryFilters($filters)` also. Using `range` just for one `(price gte, lte)` works good, but cant use it for multiple fields `(price, quantity)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You basically need something like this that uses `bool/must` with two `range` filters:

```
{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "filter": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "range": {
                "price": {
                  "gt": 555,
                  "lt": 5555
                }
              }
            },
            {
              "range": {
                "quantity": {
                  "gt": 33
                }
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

So, your `queryFilters` function needs to build the above query out of the query string you're getting. I guess it's pretty straightforward from there on.

Comment: Thanks, so, should is something like 'OR' and 'must' is 'AND'